# Customize prompt when using vcs_info in zsh

Tags: git, zsh

The following is my `.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd() { vcs_info }

zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '(%b)'

setopt PROMPT_SUBST

PROMPT='%F{blue}%B%1/%b%f %F{red}%B${vcs_info_msg_0_}%b%f > '
```

I am nit picking and trying to fix one thing but I am not sure how to do it. IF I am in a git repo I get the following prompt:

`git-repo-123 (branch-323232) >`

But if I'm NOT in a git repo I get the following prompt:

`some-non-git-repo-dir  >`

As you can see, there are two spaces between `some-non-git-repo-dir` and the `>` when I am not in a git repo. How can I fix this? I know this is super minor but I'm not sure what to put in google to help me arrive at a solution. I am pretty new to zsh and am trying to configure my shell to my liking. Thanks to all of those who response in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By examining the `PROMPT` string, you'll notice that it consists of five blocks:

1. in blue the current directory
2. SPACE
3. in red the git branch
4. SPACE
5. the prompt indicator (`>` )

So, if you're not inside a git repo, the third block will be empty and you end up with two adjacent blanks (block 2 and 4).

What you want is the blank of block 4 only if you're inside a git repo. You can achieve this for example by putting the blank into the `vcs_info` style and ommiting it from the `PROMPT`, like so:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '(%b) '
PROMPT='%F{blue}%B%1/%b%f %F{red}%B${vcs_info_msg_0_}%b%f> '
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!